# how can i get script exit status with python?

Tags: python

I have bash script that run and return and exit code 70. I try to get the exit code with python but it will only get 0 which is different.

my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
raspistill -vf -hf -o /home/pi/camera/$DATE.jpg

echo $?
```

Output

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

70
```

my python code

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir("/test")
result = subprocess.Popen("./test.sh")
text = result.communicate()[0]
returncode = result.returncode
print (returncode)
```

Output

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates

70
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your bash script is 0. `raspistill` exited abnormally (exit code 70). The `return` command in bash sets the return value for your script.

Answer (score 0):

The return code is the exit status of the last command executed in the script. Since `echo $?` ran successfully, the exit status is 0. Try the script without the echo.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is:

```
exit(returncode)
```